# Using cardslib with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm very new at Android developing, this is my first time using Android Studio as an IDE and using gradle system.

I was using [cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) in Eclipse with ADT once and it's going well, this time I tried to use it in Android Studio, but I can't and I don't know what is going on.

I already add dependencies into build.gradle,

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.5.0' //this line
}
```

Gradle sync is fine but I can't run in my phone (Android 4.2.1) the console said:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Pocket Coin:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I already tried remove **compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.5.0'** line, gradle sync was fine and I can run it.

Thanks.
(PS. I'm not native English speaker, some of text might be wrong, I'm very sorry.)

**EDIT1:**
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.pix7.pocketcoin"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="me.pix7.pocketcoin.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try to run gradle with --info option, to collect more details.
Also post your Manifest.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Added AndroidManifest, also may I ask you how can I run --info in Android Studio, please?
And, thank you for answering my question, I really like your library because it's beautiful and easy to develop with.

Comment: You can add the --info option in Preferences > Compiler > Gradle > Command-line Options. The output will appear in the "Gradle Console" tool window.